# Call Python function from Pig script

Tags: python, apache-pig, putty

I am new to Pig and would like to call a local python file from Pig after I have connected to the server via PuTTy. Below are the codes I have tried and the error message I received:

```
REGISTER ‘myudf.py’ using jython as my_udf
```

The error message is below and I don't know how to tell Pig the path to the py file.

```
File myudf.py does not exist
```

Another code i tried is:

```
DEFINE mycommand `python myudf.py` ship(‘C:\Users\myname\Documents\code\myudf.py’)；
```

The error message is

```
unexpected character ’S’
```

This may sound super easy but I have spent hours on it and failed. Any advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ensure both the python file and pig script are in the same folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the Python file is saved on your own computer, but you're running Pig on a server. The server doesn't have access to files on your computer.

You can transfer the file using software like WinSCP (assuming you're on Windows), or start a text editor on the server and copy/paste the text from your Python file into the text editor. For example, `vi myudf.py` or `emacs myudf.py` in PuTTy will start a text editor and create a file named `myudf.py` on the server once you've saved.

Once you've created the Python file, you might want to include the full path to your file on the server in your `REGISTER` statement to avoid confusion. (`pwd` shows your current directory on the server.)